# Ethernet configuration not working using DHCP

Tags: networking, wifi

My `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug walnut
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

My `wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdav
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="..."
    psk="..."
}
```

when I run `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` I get nothing.

I want to use ethernet when i'm at the lab and wifi when at home. So, use ethernet if available, otherwise use wifi. But it seems to try and connect to the same router IP address when though they are different networks.

Comment: This is not pi-specific and would be more appropriate on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).